# Prisma: Build a list containing only the domain models

Tags: typescript, database, prisma

when creating an instance *prisma* of PrismaClient (`const prisma = new PrismaClient()`), the created instance contains the domain models along with a set of database "utility" methods like $connect, $disconnect, $executeRaw, $extends...

I have a case where I would like to pass my Prisma models into a Repository class instance r:

```
export class PrismaPostRepo implements IPostRepo {
  private models: Models;

  constructor(models: Models) {
    this.models = models
  }

  //...
}
```

I'm not it is a good idea to pass all the database utility related methods along with the models to my repository instance. I believe that it should not be possible for my repository to manipulate anything else than the models.

Therefore, I am wondering if the is a way to create a new object that contains only a subset of the methods on my prisma instance. It should exclude all utility methods and containing only the models.

So if I define User, Post, UserPosts as my schema.prisma file, I would like to end up with a Models object "m" containing only my 3 models: user, post, userPosts.

If you think it is ok to pass prisma directly into my repository, please let me know why.

Thanks in advance for your help :-)